# How do i add OR in between where using linq to entity query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I wanted to search for multiple values from the same column using OR in linq. In SQL, it is something like this:

```
var query = "Select * from table where id = 1";
query += "OR where id = 2";
```

The id is from an array of ids so i pass the id to a variable and loop it. The number of id in the array is not fixed and depends on how many ids chosen by the user by checking on the checkbox in the table. Because if i do as below, it will return null because it somewhat inteprets my where query as AND. How do i change it so that it will get rows from all ids(using OR)?

```
Request request = db.Requests;
var selectedIdList = new List<string>(arrId);
if (arrId.Length > 0)
{
   for (var item = 0; item <= selectedIdList.Count() - 1; item++)
   {
      var detailId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedIdList[item]);

      request = request.Where(y => y.Id == detailId);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `selectedIdList`, and what type is `item`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include. selectedIdList is array of string, item is integer simply to loop the query so it appends the where query as many as the number of id in the array list

Comment: You need to create predicate first Follow this
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/

Comment: @Alex are you the one who posted your answer yesterday? Why did you delete it? I am about to accept and upvote your answer because it works and what i'm looking for

Comment: @Nurul now check I re-posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LinqKit. Linqkit provides things to create predicate dynamically

Just install linqKit using packageManager, And use predicateBuilder to build predicate

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Patient>();

predicate=predicate.And(...)
```

OR

```
predicate=predicate.Or(...)
```

And then use predicate in ur where clause

This way you can create Or (dynamically) as you would in dynamic SQL

You can get more details from here
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `||` for **OR** and `&&` for **AND** inside **Where**

But I prefer :

```
request.Where(y => selectedIdList.Contains(y.Id));
```

If selectedIdList is an array of Strings :

```
request.Where(y => selectedIdList.Contains(y.Id.ToString());
```

Comment: I agree that is doable, but only if i know how many id that is going to be searched. But the problem is the array is not fixed, it depends on the id that is chosen/checked by the user from the table

Comment: @Nurul If you use my preferred solution then there is no need to know the number of IDs which saved in the array